# Вызвать finish() после завершения асинхронной функции

Tags: android, static

Открываю активити, заполняю нужные поля, отправляю запрос на создание заявки на сервер.

```
CreateOrderAtServer = new CreateAtServer();
CreateOrderAtServer.execute();
//***********
public static class CreateAtServer extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer>{
```

Сервер возвращает результат и, если заявка создалась, нужно закрыть текущую Activity.
В onPostExecute пишу finish();
Ругается на вызов non-static функции из static
Как это правильно делать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно конечно хранить ссылку на контекст внутри `AsyncTask`-a и потом "скастовать" контекст к активити, и вызвать `finish()`, но это плохой подход.

Лучше всего сделать это с помощью интерфейса.

Создаете интерфейс

```
public interface TaskCallback {
    void done();
}
```

Имплементируете вашу активити от этого интерфейса, реализуете метод `done()`

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements TaskCallback {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

        new MyAsyncTask(this).execute();

    }

    @Override
    public void done() {
        finish();
    }
```

`AsyncTask` класс приобретает следующий вид

```
private static class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        private TaskCallback mCallback;

        MyAsyncTask(TaskCallback callback) {
            mCallback = callback;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            mCallback.done();
        }
    }
```